# Apply XSLT to root elements with more than one namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have very limited experience using XML and XSLT. I’m working with a large amount (about 4,000) highly standardized XML files. I’m very hesitant to edit the XML files, instead I would just like to code an XSLT file to display the tags nicely. The problem I have is that the root element has several namespaces declared on it.

When there is only one namespace, everything works fine.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ex10.xsl"?>
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
    <LCCN>05040166</LCCN>
    <call>GN800.B62</call>
    <author>Edward Thomas Stevens</author>
    <title>Flint chips</title>
    <publisher>London: Bell and Daldy, 1870.</publisher>
    <subject>Archaeology--Stone age.</subject>
</record>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" exclude-result-prefixes="a" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a:record/a:title"/>
                    by <xsl:value-of select="a:record/a:author"/>
                    , located <xsl:value-of select="a:record/a:call"/>
                </p>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But when there is one more namespace declared on the root element, I don’t know what to do.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ex10.xsl"?>
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:cinclude="http://apache.org/cocoon/include/1.0">
    <LCCN>05040166</LCCN>
    <call>GN800.B62</call>
    <author>Edward Thomas Stevens</author>
    <title>Flint chips</title>
    <publisher>London: Bell and Daldy, 1870.</publisher>
    <subject>Archaeology--Stone age.</subject>
</record>
```

The result I am trying to get is an plain text statement of TITLE by AUTHOR, located at CALL NUMBER. But when I attach the second XML file to the previous XSLT file, it no longer displays properly. I'm assuming this is because of the second namespace declaration, as that is the only thing changed. I would like to get the original result even with the second namespace defalcation.

I don't want to delete the extra namespaces because they are part of a standard (MARCXML standard by the Library of Congress). I would like to keep the original XML files as un-edited as possible.

Comment: For the XML you have shown, your XSLT will work in both cases. In the second case, the namespace prefix `cinclude` is being declared, but it is not being used anywhere. Perhaps you have oversimplified your sample a bit too much, but what problem are you actually experiencing? Thanks

Comment: Actually "cinclude" doesn't appear anywhere on the original XML document, it's very strange. All the XML files I'm working with are using the MARCXML standard by the Library of Congress. All these files have  <record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" xmlns:cinclude="http://apache.org/cocoon/include/1.0" xmlns:zs="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/"> in there root element, but none of them use any prefixes. But because these are standardized files, I don't want to go in and delete anything. Here a link to the full XML file, https://lccn.loc.gov/05040166/marcxml

Comment: The XML you have shown has a different structure. Your xslt is looking for `title`, `author` and `call` elements, none of which occur in that full XML. For that XML, to get the author, for example, you would do `a:record/a:datafield[@tag='100']/a:subfield[@code='a']`, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work :(  But the it actually does work when I remove all the namespaces except  xmlns="loc.gov/MARC21/slim" this leads me to believe that the problem is with the other namespaces in the root element.

Comment: That is odd. I tested it at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvR and that seems to work fine.

Comment: Actually that does work!! I'm not really sure what I did differently though, I'm going to have work backwards from the solution. But that's not important, the important thing is that it actually works!! Thank you so much, this has been super helpful!!

Comment: Is it producing the correct output, or dumping everything in the XML?  If it's the latter, your built in templates are dumping the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a namespace in your XML that does not have a prefix, you have to put it into the XSLT stylesheet tag with a prefix.  And you can NOT add the prefix you used to exclude-result-prefixes.  Instead, you have to use the prefix in your code to reference elements in that namespace.  In the code below, I changed the "/" to "record" in your template match, so I could use the namespace.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
              xmlns:a="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
              xmlns:cinclude="http://apache.org/cocoon/include/1.0"
              exclude-result-prefixes="cinclude" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="a:record">
  <html>
    <body>
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="a:title"/>
        by <xsl:value-of select="a:author"/>
        , located <xsl:value-of select="a:call"/>
      </p>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```